# Angular2 adding item to an array in typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Am retrieving data from database and i would like to add a number column to the data

```
users:any[];

onGetUsers() {
    this._userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
        res => {
            this.users = res
            for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
                //append the value of i to each row of the users
            }
            this.initialloading = false;
        }
    );
}
```

I would like to append the value of `i` to each row of the users array.

So the final data can be

```
currently when i console.log(users) am getting
users:
 firstname:name1, second:name2 ....
 firstname: john, second:king ...
```

Now i would like to add another column called no to the returned users array in the for loop so that i have

```
users:
 no:0, firstname:name1, second:name2 ....
 no:1, firstname: john, second:king ...
```

How do i go about this

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
this.users = res
this.users.map((user, i) => user.no = i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple because you use any[].

```
for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++){
    res[i].no = i;
}
```

But you do not iterate through res, you iterate through users

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++){
    users[i].no = i;
}
```

...or with forEach!

```
this.users.forEach((user,index) -> {
    user.no = index;
});
```